# Skills using APL/APLA on 3gen (ship1.1) devices

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing 2 Alexa skills using features of APL/APLA. They run perfectly on 2gen echo show devices, however they have many problems on 3gen (new OS 1.1 ship 1561/91) echo show. Streaming is always shut down about 30-40 seconds after starting, sometimes touchable items do not work , etc.

On the other hand I have some other skills which do not use APL and they work without any problems on both 2gen and 3gen.

Have you experienced this problem? Is there a way to make the skills work on both 2gen and 3gen devices?. Maybe I am missing some config to allow the skills run also on 3gen.I have seached on Alexa documentation and I have found nothing about it.

Comment: From the Alexa slack channel this week, perhaps this is the issue ? :  "Just a bit of a warning to anyone who has made any skills that are APL heavy on commands and tick handlers. They seem to be crashing on echo show 5 and 8
No error gets sent but the skill will crash randomly after a bit of use. Worth testing your skill and reaching out to amazon if you are also getting any issues. Error seems to have been introduced by amazon last week."

Comment: Thanks, yes the problematic skills use many APL features, though I would not say heavily. It could be the case. The problem appeared last week. As soon as I unboxed my 3gen it got updated with the referred OS version.

Comment: Regarding the APL/APLA issues, when interacting with options for this skill on device, APL is sending events on touching the box as expected, however, would you be able to check on skill's backend logs to confirm if skill is receiving this end event device or any directives ?

We are also looking into the APLA issue related to streaming getting shutdown, and it might help if you could help reproduce the problem, record the time and timezone and share details if possible

Would you be able to help share details on case raised via contact us (caseId=14867411111) please ?